# How to vertically align div inside Bootstrap 3 column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I have a page with Twitter Bootstrap `container-fluid` class `div`, one `row` and one `col-md-6` inside that row. Row is set to 50% height of the container, and a column has 100% height of the row. I have a `div` inside that column, that I want to be in the center of the column.

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid cont">
        <div class="row logoRow">
            <div class="col-md-6 logoCol">
                <div class="logoCont center-block"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the style is:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.cont {
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
.logoRow {
    height: 50%;
    background: green;
}
.logoCol {
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}

.logoCont {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
}
```

Here is my fiddle of this: http://jsfiddle.net/p9ou30g7/2/

Adding a `center-block` class to inner div aligned it to horizontal center, but I also need to align it vertically to the center of the column. 
So that red div is in the center of the yellow one. 
How can this be done?

Comment: `line-height` is the easiest option, if possible

Comment: Provide the fiddle with content inside.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is one way to do it, and is more crossbrowser supported than flexbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/p9ou30g7/3/

```
.logoCont {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
}
```

There are other ways that you can check out here: 
https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Fantastic solution. This did it for me. Very helpful fiddle :)) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [CSS3 Flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

Just add another CSS rule like this (I modified a little bit the other rules to give the divs fixed sizes so you can see the effect) :

```
.flexbox {
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-flow: column;
}
```

and add it to your HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6 logoCol flexbox">
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1td4Lg5k/

And this must be important to see [Can I use flex?](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Hope it helps

Comment: Your answer is awesome, solved my problem within a millisecond !

Answer (score 2):

Alter the outer div with

```
style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%);"
```

Worked for my login box

```
<div class="mainbox col-md-3"... style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%);">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-title">Login</div>
  </div>
</div>
```